# Capital losses treatment

Tags: united-states, non-resident, capital-loss

I incurred capital losses as a resident alien in the USA. Now, having left the USA, I am a non-resident alien and I am given to understand that I do not have to show capital gains or losses on the tax return form. Does this mean I cannot deduct any of the said losses from future capital gains from now on?

Answer (score 1):

Capital Gains arising from not effectively connected income (Schedule NEC) of 1040-NR, i.e. Stock, Bond, Savings Account, are exempt from US Capital Gains Tax. So if you had Capital Loss carryover, there is nothing to offset with.

"Capital gains of aliens **present** in the United States 183 days or more if such gains and losses were **effectively connected** with the conduct of a trade or business within the United States"

For Effectively Connected Income (ECI) and if you are present but not deemed as resident, according to 26 U.S. Code §871. (a)(2),

> such gains and losses shall be determined without regard to section
>   1202 and such losses shall be determined **without the benefits of the**
>   **capital loss carryover** provided in section 1212.

Either way, NEC or ECI, your past Capital Loss is useless.

Comment: Thank you. What if I become a resident alien again in the future?